# Changing $PATH doesn't work?

Tags: environment-variables

I was trying to set PATH in etc/environment file, but after adding the desired path the $PATH is showing an error in terminal:

> bash:
>   /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:
>   No such file or directory

Here's the content of environment file:

> PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/monty/google_appengine"

I was trying to add the path to the folder `google_appengine` to the `PATH` as mentioned in this [Answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/170240/66962),  but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Rinzwind Actually, I'm guessing he checked the path by just typing `$PATH` into the terminal, rather than `echo $PATH`

Comment: @glibdud exactly, but what's the problem here? `echo $PATH` returns `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin` for **root** , and for other users it returns `/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games.
`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After adding to the path in `/etc/environment`, you'll need to log out of your user session and back in. After that, it should pick up the new path.

Comment: okay, let me try that.

Comment: It didn't work for me, so I used .xsessionrc: http://superuser.com/a/687401/281323

Comment: surely there's a simpler way to reload the global environment variables?