# how to read an enviroment variable declared in /etc/environment from bash?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, environment-variables

How do I [read](https://askubuntu.com/q/215443/847449) or access the `TRAVERSE` environment variable below?

```
nicholas@gondor:~$ 
nicholas@gondor:~$ printenv | grep PATH
WINDOWPATH=2
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
nicholas@gondor:~$ 
nicholas@gondor:~$ printenv | grep TRAVERSE
nicholas@gondor:~$ 
nicholas@gondor:~$ cat /etc/environment
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"



TRAVERSE="/home/nicholas/some_directory"
nicholas@gondor:~$
```

I ran `source ~/.bashrc` without result.  I expect that if I were to reboot the variable would be readable, but that seems extreme.

see also:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/39296472/4531180

Comment: Did you relogin after having added the TRAVERSE variable to `/etc/environment`?

Comment: no, I was trying to avoid that.  I plan to muck around with some vars for a bit.  that's the only way @GunnarHjalmarsson to reload or refresh the vars?

Comment: I'd say it's the "right" way. But you can simply do `source /etc/environment` which will update the current bash process with your latest changes. Well, new variables won't be exported to the environment that way, but only available as shell variables.

Comment: By definition, `/etc/environment` is read at login, by the login process, before shell or GUI is started, and only at that time. So relogin is a proper way to apply changes in this file.

Comment: The full syntax of  `/etc/environment` differs a lot from that of shell scripts, so while your particular file could be sourced, not all valid environment files can be.

Comment: If you just want it for your current shell, why not just set and export the variable yourself?

Comment: @muru: Possibly you mix it up with the `~/.pam_environment` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the bash shell

```
. /etc/environment
```

without the dot the variables defined in the script file are not passed to your current shell.

For Example:

```
$ cat b.sh
TRAVERSE="Another SomeThing"
$ echo $TRAVERSE

$ ./b.sh
$ echo $TRAVERSE

$ . ./b.sh
$ echo $TRAVERSE
Another SomeThing
$
```

Comment: `source /etc/environment` should work though

Comment: yes, `source /etc/environment` works.  thanks, it was a bit late at night.